# UITableView ScrollToRowAtIndexPath method not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I have a UITableView as a subview of a View.  In the ViewController when the table is being populated I'm highlighting one of the rows and keeping a record of the indexPath for that row.  I'm doing this in the cellforRowAtIndexPath method.

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
favouriteCellView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseID"];

QBCOCustomObject *favouriteObject = [_favouriteResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (favouriteObject.userID == self.user.ID) {
    UIView *bgColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:173.0f/255.0f green:146.0f/255.0f blue:237.0f/255.0f alpha:.5];
    self.highlightedRowIndex = indexPath;
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColor];
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
}
return cell;
```

}

Then in the viewDidAppear Method I want the table to scroll to the highlighted cell.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.highlightedRowIndex atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];      
}
```

However I've double checked that the method is being hit with a breakpoint, but unfortunately the highlighted row is not being scrolled to the top of the table as I'd expected. AM I misunderstanding the scrollToRowAtIndexPath method?  Or have I left something out of the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the row is not on screen, it will not yet be loaded by the table view. This means your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for that cell will not yet be called. You'll want to choose this index in a way that does not depend on the view loading. Try this before you call `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`:

```
NSInteger row = 0;
for (QBCOCustomObject *object in _favouriteResults) {
  if (object.userID == self.user.ID) break;
  row++;
}
self.highlightedRowIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
```